# Что хранится в дамп файле после exporta и как его импортировать?

Tags: oracle, импорт, export

Не подскажете, что хранится в файле .dat после exporta и как его импортировать?

```
user/********@DB DUMPFILE=dump.dat LOGFILE=dump.dat.log EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN('Xxx','yyy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В dat находится сам дамп + возможно индексы и всякие объекты. Файл бинарный. Его можно импортировать с помощью impdp. Для того, чтобы сделать это, файл дампа должен лежать в определённом месте (его нельзя импортировать откуда угодно). Есть множество описаний в интернете. Воспользуйтесь же Google, наконец. [Вот](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Data+Pump+Export+(expdp)+and+Data+Pump+Import(impdp)), например, или [тут](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump)... [тут](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm)

Answer (score 2):

В параметре `DUMPFILE` указан файл или набор файлов дампа. Файлы дампа записываются в проприетарном, бинарном формате. Дамп содержит метаданные объектов БД, табличные данные и некоторую управляющую информацию.

Так как параметр `DIRECTORY` отсутствует, файлы дампа записываются в каталог по умолчанию, который можно узнать так:

```
select directory_path from all_directories
where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

После экспорта файл(ы) дампа могут быть перемещены на другой сервер БД для импорта. Импорт осуществляется утилитой `impdp` с указанием целевой БД:

```
impdp user/********@DB2 DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=dump.dat LOGFILE=import.log
```

Подробней в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump.html#GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A).